# Is it possible to make the cooldown time only last while a command is running in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm developing a discord bot, and one of it's features is a command that feeds memes, it's only available for some channels I'm the server, and I wanted to know if it's possible to put the command in cooldown while it's being used, then a new feed couldn't be started while there's already one feed being executed, also I wanted this to only happen at a channel, for example: A user used the feed command in channel-1, of him or someone try to start a new feed before the current one ends it will fail, but if another feed is started at channel-2 it should work.

I don't know if it's possible, but if yes, how should it be done? I'm currently using @commands.cooldown decorator to put a normal cooldown on the command.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the way to do it is without using the `@commands.cooldown` decorator and some custom way of doing the cooldown.

```py
# use datetime
import datetime

# define this somewhere
meme_feed_cooldowns = {}

.
.
.

@client.command(description="feed memes")
async def meme_feed(ctx):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    
    previous_time_triggered = meme_feed_cooldowns.get(channel_id, None)

    if previous_time_triggered:
        # check if we're in cooldown
        time_since_triggered = now - previous_time_triggered
        if time_since_triggered.total_seconds() < 1800:
            # it's not been 30 minutes since last triggered
            # send some kind of message to inform the user and then return
            return
    
    # set the cooldown time to the current time
    meme_feed_cooldowns[channel_id] = now

    # do whatever you want to do
```

Something *kind of* like this. There's other improvements you could make - make the "*cooldown dict*" more complicated and also have whether or not the command is ongoing. Hopefully gives you enough ideas to get you going!